# Use localStorage variable inside WHERE clause with SharePointPlus

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepointplus

I use SharePointPlus and I'm trying to use localStorage variable in the WHERE clause. Below my code:

```
$SP().list('Pracownicy').get({
  fields:"SID,Dost_x0119_py,Dost_x0119_py_Zam,Dzia_x0142_,Rola",
  where:"SID = localStorage.getItem('sid')"
  ....
```

This variable is a string. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Is it possible to use such variable there? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a string you must also include quotes :

```
$SP().list('Pracownicy').get({
  fields:"SID,Dost_x0119_py,Dost_x0119_py_Zam,Dzia_x0142_,Rola",
  where:'SID = "' + localStorage.getItem('sid') + '"' 
  ....
```

It would also be better to test the return of your local storage before using it, like :

```
var sid = localStorage.getItem('sid');
if (!sid) alert("error") 
else {
  $SP().list('Pracownicy').get({
  fields:"SID,Dost_x0119_py,Dost_x0119_py_Zam,Dzia_x0142_,Rola",
  where:'SID = "' + sid + '"' 
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SharePoint Plus, but I think the right way to get the local storage and add to your where clausule is:

```
"SID = " + localStorage.getItem('sid'),
```

and remove comma(,) if **where** is the last property.

The way you're doing:

`"SID = localStorage.getItem('sid')"`

are making the code understand that `localStorage.getItem('sid')` is a String instead of variable;

Comment: It doesn't work. Unfortunately I suppose it must be specific string.